# Simple data structure

Tags: prolog

The following simple Prolog program represents, through the use of data structure, a family composed of husband, wife and children list:

```
family(
    person(bob, smith, date(7,may,1968), 30000),
    person(ann, smith, date(18,july,1970), 32000),

    [person(dave, smith, date(1,june,1984), 0),
     person(edna, smith, date(25,may,1990), 0)]
).

family(
    person(mario, rossi, date(7,may,1968), 30000),
    person(lucia, verdi, date(18,july,1970), 32000),

    [person(luca, rossi, date(1,june,1984), 0),
     person(maria, rossi, date(25,may,1990), 0),
     person(paolo, rossi, data(16, april, 1980), 10000)]
).

family(
    person(carlo, bianchi, date(7,may,1968), 30000),
    person(flavia, blabla, date(18,july,1970), 32000),

    [person(figlio1, bianchi, date(1,june,1984), 0),
     person(figlio2, bianchi, date(25,may,2001), 0),
     person(figlio3, bianchi, data(16, april, 1980), 10000),
     person(figlio4, bianchi, data(10, april, 1978), 20000)]
).

family(
    person(no, no, date(7,may,1968), 30000),
    person(no, no, date(18,july,1970), 32000),
    []
).


/* Regola che mostra i mariti: */
husband(X) :- family(X,_,_).

/* Regola che mostra l mogli: */
wife(X) :- family(_,X,_).

/* Regola che mostra i figli:
   X è figlio se in una famiglia c'è una lista di figli e se X appartiene
   alla lista dei figli: */
child(X) :- family(_,_,Children),
        member(X,Children).
```

This is very simple. By some facts I represent some family and I have some rule to perform some query (to obtain the husbands, the wifes, if X is a child in a family, if a person exist in a family, the salary of a person and the date of birth of a person)

Ok, until now I have no problem.

Then I have the following exercise related to the previous program: **Write a rule to obtain all the families that don't have child**

My idea is that a family have no child if the children list is an empty list. Obtain a family that have not child means show the husband and wife names of these families and I solve it adding this rule to the previous program:

```
nochildren(X,Y) :- family(X,Y,[]).
```

It work but I don't know if it is a clean solution because the user (that perform the query in the Prolog shell) have to know that X represents the husband name and that Y represents the wife name.

Are there better solutions?

Comment: @reinierpost: Why is this a better title?

Comment: @false: it is at least somewhat specific. the present title could refer to pretty much anything in programming.

Comment: @reinierpost: It had absolutely nothing to do with the content of the post.

Comment: @false: I took it from the first line of the accepted answer.

Comment: @reinierpost: We agree that the question is relevant for the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You raise a good general question about naming conventions for Prolog predicates. A good rule of thumb is to use a name that makes clear *what* the arguments are. For example, if the first argument is a husband and the second his wife, a starting point for a predicate name could be:

`husband_wife(X, Y) :- ...`

However, in your case, the name should also make clear that a specific property holds in addition, namely that the couple has no children. What about:

`childless_husband_wife(X, Y) :- ...`

Seems clear enough to me.

You could raise the same question about `family/3`. A much better name in my opinion would be `husband_wife_children/3`, since it makes clear what its arguments are. We end up with:

`childless_husband_wife(H, W) :- husband_wife_children(H, W, []).`

Comment: ok, tnx so much...only a last explanation. If an user (that perform query) have no access to the source code of the Prolog program how can he know the list and the names of the arguments of a function (and also the name of the functions that he can use to perform the query)? if it is possible

Comment: You can provide them to the user, for example, by implementing a `help/1` predicate that somehow displays usage guidelines of your program, or for example by documenting available relations with a predicate like `predicate_description/2` that users can query.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to find a balance between self-documentation and unwieldiness of `very_long_predicate_names`. IMHO

```
childless(Husb,Wife):-    % a childless family
  family(Husb,Wife,[]).
```

is about right. I.e. we can use suggestive names for predicates, *and* their arguments, as self-documenting feature. Comments are good as well.